# Delicious app using django and google app engine

Tags: sql, django, google-app-engine

Hi every one 
i em planning to develop an app like [delicious](http://www.delicious.com/) .
in this app i would like to simply add book marks as Delicious.
First the user should be authenticated using a user name and password and after successful authentication the user can add bookmarks to his profile exactly like delicious.
i would like to deploy it on Google App Engine, using sql database.
what i would like to know is, that is django fully compatible with goggle app engine.
which features are supported and which features of django are not supported by goggle app engine.

the authentication process will be handled by django itself as i have already written a module for authentication in django and don't want to use openID or something like that. Does Google app engine supports this  as well. any suggestions, comments and helps will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Googled that for you.](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html) :)

(Note: that article replaces the [previous instructions](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html) for running Django on GAE.)

Comment: thanks for ur help djacabson i have got another link as well http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel.html

Comment: Um... yes. Your link looks good, too. Anyrate, you're welcome. :)

Comment: Also, note that you can't use SQL on App Engine.